# How to refresh UITextField within UITableViewCell after data selection from modal

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield, modalviewcontroller

I have a tableview with UITextFields to build a form. I then have a button in the toolbar which launches a modal view controller to select some data which is then passed back to the tableview. However, the new data that was selected does not get refreshed into the UITextField using textField.text = valueReturnedFromModal syntax. Is there something I'm missing?

I see that the data is being returned properly from the modal so that is not the issue. I'm just having trouble forcing the UITextField to refresh with the new data. I've tried forcing a reloadData on the tableview as well.

So from the modal view, here's the code that passes data back:

```
- (void)doneAccountSelection:(id)sender
{
    [delegate didSelectAccount:currentAccount];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

and here's the actual method in the delegate:

```
- (void)didSelectAccount:(SFAccount *)selectedAccount
{
    //Ensure a valid deal exists for the account to be attached to
    [self createDealObjectIfNeeded];

    //Set the deal account
    [self.deal setAccount:selectedAccount];

    //Refresh the text fields
    //Tag 3: Account Name field
    UITextField *acct_name = (UITextField *) [self.view viewWithTag:3];
    [acct_name setText:self.deal.account.field_acct_name_value];

    //Tag 4: Account City field
    UITextField *acct_city = (UITextField *) [self.view viewWithTag:4];
    [acct_city setText:self.deal.account.field_acct_city_value];

    //Save the context changes. A new deal gets created above if one does not exist.
    if ([self saveModel]) NSLog(@"Acct object created, attached to deal successfully!");

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some serious debugging found that `self.account` was being used in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to set the initial `UITextField` values within the `UITableViewCell`. Then after modal selection completed, I was only updating the account reference for the deal object and not updating the `self.account` object.

I then added to this by creating a new method called `updateTextFieldsAfterModalFinished` and moved the code to update the `UITextField`s there. This method was then called from `didSelectAccount` which is the delegate method for modal view that is dismissed. Things are now working as expected and the `UITextFields` get updated after modal selection is finished.

Answer (score 0):

use this after getting Value in text field:

```
[self.tableView ReloadData];
```

Comment: If I'm understanding your answer correctly then the textfield is not initiating the modalview so this won't work. The modal view is returning the data back to a delegate method in the tableviewcontroller and within that function I need to update the text in the textfields.

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind posting the code that sets the text fields data and the code that passes the data back to the table view?

Answer:

It appears that you are properly setting the data, however, you are dismissing the modal view controller after sending the delegate message. In this scenario, the table view is not even created until after the dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: has ended. Which means the textfields are NULL until the view is present. What I suggest is call

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

as the first line in the didSelectAccount: delegate method. This would dismiss the modal view and then continue on with your setting the data to valid textfields as -viewWillAppear: / -viewDidAppear: would have already been called. Everything seems ok it's just the order that may be tripping you up. Although

```
-dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:
```

is passed to its parent if a view controller does not have a modal view (because it is the modal view), it seems more appropriate to call this method in the delegate method where you will eventually manipulate the view due to new data, etc.

Comment: Brian, I tried what you recommended. I moved

`[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

to the beginning of `didSelectAccount:` method but to no luck.

Comment: You have have the method -createDealObjectIfNeeded. Is this setting the deal property of self? If not, where is that code?

Comment: `case 1:
            if (indexPath.row == 0)
            {
                cell.lblFieldName.text = @"Name";
                if (account) cell.txtFieldValue.text = account.field_acct_name_value;
                cell.txtFieldValue.tag = 3;
            }
            if (indexPath.row == 1)
            {
                cell.lblFieldName.text = @"City";
                if (account) cell.txtFieldValue.text = account.field_acct_city_value;
                cell.txtFieldValue.tag = 4;
            }
            break;`

Comment: Here's what `createDealObjectIfNeeded:` does:
`- (void)createDealObjectIfNeeded
{
    //If no deal object exists, create the deal object first
    if (self.deal == nil)
    {
        SFDeal *d = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"SFDeal" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
        
        self.deal = d;
        //Set demo data and deleted flags to identify new deals as 'real' data
        [self.deal setDemoDataFlag:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
        [self.deal setDeletedFlag:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
    }
}`

Comment: You refer to [self.view viewWithTag: number]; when really isn't the textfield part of the UITableViewCell?

Comment: Also, in a similar scenario, instead of tags, I used a weak property to point to these UITextFields (they are already retained by the UITableViewCell). I then was able to directly refer to them after -viewWillAppear: by self.firstNameField or self.LastNameField after properly setting them up in a separate method aptly named setupTextFields.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8878/discussion-between-brian-palma-and-m-azam)